# Wiping , disabling everything on a Pi 4

Tags: pi-4

I setup my Raspberry Pi4 but now I want my grandchild to start from absolute scratch with it. How do I delete everything, and make it as if its never been used?

Comment: Copy a new image of Raspberry Pi OS (or an operating system of your choice) onto the SD card.

Comment: Better still buy a s new SD Card and do a fresh install. You can keep the old or re-cycle it later.

Comment: Better still, buy a new SD card and do nothing with it - if you want someone to start from absolute scratch, use a blank SD card

Comment: Jaromanda has a good point in that the recipient may need to do so later and will be less hesitant if they've done it before (and if they know that's how what they would be overwriting was done in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

You must first determine if your grandchild has ["The Knack"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8vHhgh6oM0). Scatter a few parts around the house, and let him find them. Don't offer a word of advice. If he does have "The Knack", it really won't matter if you delete everything or not... he'll be mining Bitcoin in a day or two.

Having indulged my penchant for bizarre humor, let me offer this answer:

Once you've determined "The Knack" isn't present, maybe buy him a new SD card, give him the parts in a box, and a pointer toward the online instructions. Be there to answer questions, or offer suggestions. In my experience, a child who sees a parent or grandparent engrossed in something is naturally attracted to learn about that. Maybe that's the first step - let him see you engaged in it, and develop some curiosity.